# Inflating a RecyclerView in the context of a SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I previously created a RecyclerView that has been working fine as well as a SlidingTabLayout with a ViewPager that displays a simple TextView.

But I want to combine them, with the RecyclerView being displayed under each of the tabs, however this is where I'm running into trouble.

When I was populating my ViewPager with a simple TextView, the relevant code from within my MainActivity looked like this:

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private TextView textView;

```
    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            textView.setText("The Page Currently Selected " + bundle.getInt("position"));
        }
        return layout;
    }
}
```

When I try to replace the TextView with my RecyclerView, I change the code above in the following way:

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            myFragment.setArguments(args);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
           return layout;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I've just make layout equal to the inflated layout which contains my RecyclerView.

The layout that's being inflated, fragment_games, looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxxxxxxxx.chessgame.Games_Fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gameList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Finally, the stacktrace looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for  `RecyclerView` you must have at least set LayoutManager.

See [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager))

You can try after instantiating the `RecyclerView` to set the LayoutManager like

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

> **Note** make sure you added line

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0
```

your build.gradle